# Binding to a TextBox within a ListView?

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have been searching for an answer for this for almost a week now, and I can't seem to find a way to do this. I would think it is a relatively simple thing...

I have a ListView, and one GridViewColumn contains TextBox items. I want to put a Label right underneath the ListView, and fill it with the sum of the items in all the TextBoxes. Whenever someone changes a value in any of the TextBoxes, the sum should change, too.

I know I need to use a Converter to get the sum... but I don't know how to get the binding right...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: I ended up solving this in a slightly different way. I will post my solution below.**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="myParties" XPath="Parties" Source="XMLFile1.xml" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myCollectionViewSource" Source="{StaticResource myParties}" />
        <converters:SumConverter x:Key="mySumConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="Breakpoint" Click="bpClick" Content="Breakpoint"/>
        <ListView x:Name="myListView" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollectionViewSource},XPath='Party',Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='@Contact'}" Header="Contact"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='@Qty'}" Header="Q"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='@Amount'}" Header="Amt"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="tbTot" Header="Tot">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding XPath='@Tot'}" />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>    
        </ListView>

        <Label Height="22">
            <Label.Content>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mySumConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="myListView" Path="Items"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="myListView" Path="Items.Count"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Parties>
  <Party Contact="Jim Shmekel"
         Qty="1"
         Amount="55.00" 
         Tot="55.00"/>
  <Party Contact="Shmi Skywalker"
         Qty="1"
         Amount="20.00" 
         Tot="20.00"/>
  <Party Contact="Jon Ronson"
         Qty="1"
         Amount="23.00" 
         Tot="23.00"/>
</Parties>
```

SumConverter:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Reflection

<ValueConversion(GetType(Object()), GetType(String))>
Public Class SumConverter : Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal values() As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
        Static lvItems As IList
        Static lvItem As Xml.XmlElement
        Dim nVal As Double

        Convert = 0
        lvItems = values(0)
        If lvItems Is Nothing Then Exit Function

        For Each lvItem In lvItems
            'Debug.Print(lvItem.GetAttribute("Tot"))
            If Double.TryParse(lvItem.GetAttribute("Tot"), nVal) Then
                Convert = Convert + nVal
            End If
        Next

    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetTypes() As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
        ConvertBack = Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward solution (I'm sure not the best) is to bind a

```
ElementName = myListView, Path = Items
```

And in converter traverse items and using `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild()` find out underlying TextBlock of an item and then `int.TryParse(textBlock.Text, out currentItemValue);`

Comment: Hi sllev-- thanks so much for your quick response. I think this gets me close to where I need to be, but when I run it now, it only calls my converter once when the program starts (Items.Count=0) and not again. Any ideas? (added my SumConverter code above).

Comment: @transistor1: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003074/how-can-i-add-a-value-when-i-use-groupping-by-in-datagrid/7003686#7003686). (Keypoint being: MultiBinding with one binding targeting an items.count-property to get it updated)

Comment: So when you adding items it is not called again?

Comment: @H.B. - Thanks -- that sounds logical. I'm going to try that now.

Comment: @sllev -- yes, it only gets called once. From what I've been reading it's because the Items object itself does not change when items get added to it.  H.B's multibinding makes sense because the Count should change...

Comment: This is bringing me pretty close guys, thank you so much! I need to take a break now but I am assuming this will get me where I need to be. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok... the multibinding seems to work well; but now when I access the Items object within the Converter, each individual Items.Item() is an XmlElement (the data **source**), not the Visual as I would have expected. Therefore, I _still_ can't access the contents of the TextBox (which could potentially be edited). If anyone could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: @transistor1 : XmlElement because you're using XmlDataSource which bound to Items, right? Could you update initial question with latest version fo XAML and converter?

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response, @sllev. Yes, in the `items` collection, it's an XmlElement because I'm using a XmlDataSource. I thought I'd be able to access the contents of the TextBox elements, like you had mentioned in your original post, but I can't seem to access them.  I updated all the files to what i currently have. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Try out to add third parameter - listView, without Path="Items", then in converter cast it to ListView and see in Debug mode whether you can access an items you are looking for, basically you need control collection and in for loop travetse controls using child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(), and try to cast it to TextBox you should end-up finding right textbox

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @sllev. I played around with the ListView like you said, but unfortunately I was not able to find a control collection so I ended up solving it in a slightly different way. I will post my solution below. Thanks again, you have helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit disappointed, because I really was hoping to approach this the way the sllev had suggested. To me, that seemed like the most logical way of doing it. There may still be a way, but I haven't figured it out.

Here is how I ended up solving this problem. Basically what I did was add the "Tot" column to my DataSource (it was not there in my initial solution although it is in my question above). I bound my TextBox to that column, and then refreshed the ListView on the LostFocus event of the TextBox within the ListView. The Refresh() causes the SumConverter to be called again.

Hopefully this helps someone else out - it seemed like a simple request but I have wasted a ton of time on it.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="myParties" XPath="Parties" Source="XMLFile1.xml" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="myCollectionViewSource" Source="{StaticResource myParties}" />
        <converters:SumConverter x:Key="mySumConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="myListView" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myCollectionViewSource},XPath='Party',Mode=TwoWay}">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='@Contact'}" Header="Contact"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='@Qty'}" Header="Q"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath='@Amount'}" Header="Amt"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="tbTot" Header="Tot">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <TextBox LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" Width="100" Text="{Binding XPath='@Tot'}" />
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>    
        </ListView>

        <Label VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label.Content>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource mySumConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="myListView" Path="Items"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="myListView" Path="Items.Count"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind on MainWindow.xaml:

```
Class MainWindow 

        Public Sub New()
            ' This call is required by the designer.
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Private Sub TextBox_LostFocus(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
            myListView.Items.Refresh()
        End Sub
    End Class
```

SumConverter.vb:

```
<ValueConversion(GetType(Object()), GetType(String))>
Public Class SumConverter : Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(ByVal values() As Object, ByVal targetType As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.Convert
        Static lvItems As ItemCollection
        Static lvItem As Xml.XmlElement
        Dim nVal As Double

        Convert = 0
        lvItems = values(0)
        If lvItems Is Nothing Then Exit Function


        For Each lvItem In lvItems
            'Debug.Print(lvItem.GetAttribute("Tot"))
            If Double.TryParse(lvItem.GetAttribute("Tot"), nVal) Then
                Convert = Convert + nVal
            End If
        Next

    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetTypes() As System.Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object() Implements System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack
        ConvertBack = Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```